# Unable to animate React-Konva Circle using React-Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, konvajs, react-motion

I am using React-Konva to draw shapes in my app. I have drawn a circle inside another circle and grouped them. Now, what I want to do is that on a button click the circles should animate (move horizontally). Here is my related code:

```
<Layer>
  <Motion style={{a: spring(open ? 400 : x)}}>
    {({a}) => {
      return(
        <div
          style={{
            WebkitTransform: `translate3d(${a}px, 0, 0)`,
            transform: `translate3d(${a}px, 0, 0)`,
          }}
        >
          <Group draggable={true}>
            <CircleComponent
              x={parseInt(x)}
              y={parseInt(y)}
              radius={parseInt(radius)}
              color={color}
              shadowValue={parseInt(shadowValue)}
            />
            <CircleComponent
              x={parseInt(x)}
              y={parseInt(y)}
              radius={parseInt(innerRadius)}
              color={innerColor}
            />
          </Group>
        </div>
      );}
    }
  </Motion>
</Layer>
```

Right now I am getting this error: 'Cannot read property '_idCounter' of undefined'. And this is because I'm introducing a div container inside Layer tag. But if I remove the div container and apply the transform styling to the Group tag, nothing happens. I have read the docs and the Group class doesn't accept any style props. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add `div` as a child of `Layer` because layer can have only `Konva.Group` or `Konva.Shape` as children (not DOM elements).

`Group` don't `style` property, but you can use `offsetX` and `offsetY` to achieve our effect. Something like:

```
<Group draggable={true} offsetX={a}>
```